# AJAX query error/success

Tags: jquery

Please correct me if I'm wrong but my understanding of `$.post` success/failure is if the url is valid, this will return a success. The only time this will return a failure is if the url is not valid.

If this is true, how do I validate the success function? Reason I ask is no matter what happens, I always get the same success alert even though there's error in the code behind.

Comment: Simply check the response code in the xhrObject passed to your success function. If it is not 200 you know you've got an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you handle the error server-side.

You can use a `try/catch` using a variable as a `flag true/false` and a message to identify the error case. When return to js, you check these variables to be sure that the response is ok

Comment: can you give me an example of this, please?

Comment: The solution proposed is similiar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809963/handling-php-exceptions-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

No, there are many cases where `$.post` could return an error.

From the [jQuery Source Code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), you can see that the HTTP status code is used to determine whether the request is successful:

```
// If successful, handle type chaining 
if ( status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304 ) {
```

There are many reasons why a "bad" status might be returned. It could be due to a 404 (Bad URL), but it also could be due to a 500 (Internal server error). In the latter case, an exception within the server code could trigger the error.

In order to help solve your error, you would need to provide more information. What type of error is occurring? Do you have the text of the error?

Answer (score 0):

I find **ajax.success()** naming a bit misleading. 
Also (from jQuery docs):

> The **jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete()** callbacks
>   will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their
>   eventual removal, use **jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always()**
>   instead.

As of now - **jqXHR.success()** is a simple shortcut to **jqXHR.done()**.

```
jqXHR.success = jqXHR.done;
jqXHR.error = jqXHR.fail;
jqXHR.complete = completeDeferred.done;
```

So - when jQuery calls **jqXHR.success()** (aka **jqXHR.done()**)  ?

Well - If I looked at the source correctly, two things should happen:

1) Http response code must be :

```
status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304
```

2) If there is a data coming back - parsing (from json, xml etc.) should not have errors:

```
try {
    success = ajaxConvert( s, response );
    statusText = "success";
    isSuccess = true;
} catch(e) {
    // We have a parsererror
    statusText = "parsererror";
    error = e;
}
```

---

So - to answer your question. JavaScript has no idea about what is going on in your server side code (PHP, ASP etc). What you should do is send a json response back to javascript from your serverside code, for example send 1 if there is no error and 2 if there is:

```
//php file:
//send 2 in case of an error
echo json_encode(array('error'=>2));

//js file:
if(ajaxresponse.error && ajaxresponse.error == 2) {
    alert('error happened');
}
```